# Vue router does not render/mount root path component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

i am making a page with `vue`, `vue-router` and `laravel`, the problem, when i enter in `localhost/myproject/public_html/`, the `Home` component is not rendered in the `router-view`, if i click in the router link to the Service component, it render the content normally, and when i click to the home path it render the home component content, so why this happens? this is my `app.js` structure

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './views/App'
import Home from './views/Home'
import Service from './views/Service'
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: 'servicios',
            'name' : 'services',
            component: Service
        }
    ],
});
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components : { App },
    router,
});
```

this is my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hola

        <router-link :to="{ name : 'services' }">
            ir a servicios
        </router-link>

        <router-view>
        </router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import PageLogo from '../components/PageLogo'
    import Loading from '../components/Loading'
    export default {
        mounted : function(){
            console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.path)

        },
        components : {
            'page-logo' : PageLogo,
            'loading' : Loading
        },
        methods : {
            ajaxOver : function() {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

this is my Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        Home page
        <router-link :to="{ name : 'services' }">
            go to services
        </router-link>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            console.log('hola')
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is Service.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        Services page

        <router-link :to="{ name : 'home' }">
            go to home
        </router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted : function(){
            console.log('services')
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image: this is the first load of the page, as you can see, the home component content is not being loaded]

[image: if i click in the service link, it show the content of the service component]
[image: if i click in the service component to go to home, it show the home component content]

so how can i solve this? if i reload the page in any route, the `component` should be mounted, but in the vue router is not being displayed, so the `component` is not mounted.

**Edit:**

As requested, in App.vue the log is `/myproject/public_html/`

Comment: Hi again. Can you log the output of `this.$router.currentRoute.path` in mounted in App.vue? Also, the path for Home is meant to be '/' not './', right?

Comment: Edited the route, and logged this.$router.currentRoute.path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Laravel before, but I think you're looking for [base](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base).

Vue docs:

> - type: string
> - default: "/"
>     
>   The base URL of the app. For example, if the entire single page application is served under /app/, then base should use the value "/app/".

Since you're serving your project at `localhost/myproject/public_html/`, vue is seeing `/myproject/public_html/` instead of `/`.

You can change this by adding the base route to the vue-router constructor.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/myproject/public_html/',
    ...
}
```